# Can we show badge icon on left top most corner of an app icon in iPhone instead of usual right-top-most corner display?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, push-notification, badge

I for my next project work need to display the notification badge icon to the left-top-most corner of the app icon. I went through various blogs and study materials but didn't get what I was looking up for.
Please suggest if it is possible to do so. If yes, then how? If no, then why not?

Any help much appreciated.

> Please consider adding a comment if you think this post can be improved.

Comment: Don't think it's possible, its related to system, not something your app can control I think

Comment: No, you can't. There is not method/property available for it.

Comment: it is not an application feature, its OS feature. So application side doesn't have any API to modify it

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to change the position of badge icon left top corner, Apple does not allow to change and there is no any feature to change a position of badge icon.